# Does an iron bar become heavier when magnetized?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Say I have a piece of iron bar. Would the same iron bar weigh more when being magnetized, (assuming no outside forces like magnetic field, etc,) and the scale is non-magnetic? I think you know what I'm saying.

Comment: A static magnetic field does have mass, just like any other form of mass-energy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a magnetic field will contribute to the mass of an object because [it has energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/engfie.html) and in [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) mass is the length of the fourvector:

[image: mass]

The static field has zero momentum , but it has energy, therefore from the above formula it has  an invariant mass. The densest magnetic fields are of a few tesla. I copy the answer to a [similar question](http://van.physics.illinois.edu/QA/listing.php?id=19856) which gives an estimate:

> Let's say you have a lab magnet that fills 1000 cm3 of space with a very high field of 10^5 G. That field has an energy of (roughly) 10^12 ergs. That corresponds to a mass of 10^-9 grams. So for most purposes we just forget about it.

Comment: So is mg field count as relativistic mass or rest mass?

Comment: If you are adding linearly the masses of all the atoms, it is a good approximation as the motion of the atoms is too low to make a difference to the relativistic mass. As the estimate shows the energy of a magnetic field has a mass density very small with respect to the atomic masses. So even though one should add all the energy and all the momentum vectors to get the invariant mass, which will be the correct mass for a system of atoms+fields, the difference will be infinitessimally small, that it is not worth the effort. One just adds the classical atomic masses to get the mass of an object.

Comment: @anna v, when you say "invariant mass", do you mean that it's an invariant quantity for an observer in any reference frame?

Comment: @no_choice99  yes, it is invariant to Lorenz transformations.

Comment: An iron magnet is just a normal piece of iron with many of its atoms 
magnetic moment aligned. When not magnetized, each atoms magnetic moment points into random directions, cancelling each other, therefore, magnetizing an iron bar do not add mass to the resulting magnet. The energy and mass of the magnetic field was already present even when not magnetized.

Comment: @J.Manuel mass is not an additve quantity in special relativity. When it becomes magnetized energy is expended, and conservation of energy holds.

Comment: @annav. Yep. The extra mass comes from the external source of energy used to align the already existing (but scrambled) magnetic field. However, by conservation of energy, the resulting energy stored in the macroscopically measurable magnetic field must be equal to the work done by the external source, leading to your answer anywhere. Still, for the sake of completeness, I think that you should notify the reader that to magnetize a piece of iron one must impart or perform work to the material, which will be stored in the resulting magnetic field.